# Does the g++ 4.8.2 compiler support Unicode characters?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, ascii

Consider the following statements -

```
cout<<"\U222B";

int a='A';
cout<<a;
```

The first statement prints an integration sign (the character equivalent to the Unicode code point) whereas the second cout statement prints the ASCII value 65.

So I want to ask two things -

1) If my compiler supports Unicode character set then why it is implementing the ASCII character set and showing the ascii values of the characters?

2) With reference to this question - [what is the difference in defining the 'byte' in terms of computer memory and in terms of C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570247/what-is-the-difference-in-defining-the-byte-in-terms-of-computer-memory-and-in)

Does my compiler implement 16-bit or 32-bit byte? If yes, then why do the value of CHAR_BIT is set to 8?

Comment: what's important is the console's support for Unicode, as the program simply outputs a byte sequence in some charset that will be treated some way by the console to print out, and if the console's Unicode support is bad, you can't see the expected result

Comment: `'A'` is 65 in Unicode

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your first question, the bottom 128 code points of Unicode *are* ASCII. There's no real distinction between the two.

The reason you're seeing `65` is because the thing you're outputting (`a`) is an `int` rather than a `char` (it may have *started* as a `char` but, by putting it into `a`, you modified how it would be treated in future).

---

For your second question, a byte *is* a `char`, at least as far as the ISO C and C++ standards are concerned. If `CHAR_BIT` is defined as `8`, that's how wide your `char` type is.

However, you should keep in mind the difference between Unicode *code points* and Unicode *representations* (such as UTF-8). Having `CHAR_BIT == 8` will still allow Unicode to work if UTF-8 representation is used.

My advice would be to capture the output of you program with a hex dump utility, you may well find the Unicode character is coming out as `e2 88 ab`, which is the UTF-8 representation of `U+222B`. It will then be interpreted by something outside of the program (eg, the terminal program) to render the correct glyph(s):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() { cout << "\u222B\n"; }
```

Running that program above shows what's being output:

```
pax> g++ -o testprog testprog.cpp ; ./testprog
∫

pax> ./testprog | hexdump
0000000 e2 88 ab 0a
```

You could confirm that by generating the same UTF-8 byte sequence in a different way:

```
pax> printf "\xe2\x88\xab\n"
∫
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several different questions/issues here:

1. As paxdiablo pointed out, you're seeing "65" because you're outputting "a" (value 'A' = ASCII 65) as an "int".
2. Yes, gcc supports Unicode source files: [--finput-charset=OPTION](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html)
3. The final issue is whether the C++ compiler treats your "strings" as 8-bit ASCII or n-bit Unicode.

   C++11 added explicit support for Unicode strings and string literals, encoded as UTF-8, UTF-16 big endian, UTF-16 little endian, UTF-32 big endian and UTF-32 little endian:

[How well is Unicode supported in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17103925/how-well-is-unicode-supported-in-c11)

PS:

As far as language support for Unicode:

- Java was designed from the ground up for Unicode.

  Unfortunately, at the time that meant only UTF-16.  Java 5 supported nicode 6.0, Java 7 Unicode 6.0 and the current Java 8 supports Unicode 6.2.
- .Net is newer.  C#, VB.Net and C++/CLI all fully support Unicode 4.0.

  Newer versions of .Net support newer versions of Unicode.  For example, .Net 4.0 supports Unicode 5.1]([What version of Unicode is supported by which .NET platform and on which version of Windows in regards to character classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162131/what-version-of-unicode-is-supported-by-which-net-platform-and-on-which-version)).
- Python3 also supports Unicode 4.0: http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Python3 supports Unicode 4.0". Python3 supports versions of Unicode *much* more recent than Unicode 4.0, to the extent that it is meaningful to talk about Python3 supporting a version of Unicode. As a datapoint, Python 3.5's `unicodedata` module corresponds to Unicode 8.0.0.

Comment: The last time I looked (admittedly a long time ago), Python supported Unicode 4.0.  SUGGESTION: If you have a link for current version/current Unicode support, please post it!

Comment: As I said, I don't really know what you mean by "unicode x.y.z support", since Python does no text rendering. But it is easy to trace the `unicodedata` module, which defines, for example, which letters are valid in identifiers. See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unicodedata.html#module-unicodedata (and change the version number in that URL if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For of all, sorry for my English if it has mistakes.

A C++ byte is any defined amount of bits large enough to transport every character of a set specified by the standard. This required set of characters is a subset of ASCII, and that previously defined "amount of bits" must be the memory unit for `char`s, the tiniest memory atom of C++. Every other type must be a multiple of `sizeof(char)` (any C++ value is a bunch of chars continously stored on memory).

So, `sizeof(char)` must be 1 by definition, because is the memory measurement unit of C++. If that 1 means 1 physical byte or not is an implementation issue, but universally accepted as 1 byte.

What I don't understand is what do you mean with 16-bit or 32-bit byte.

Other related question is about the encoding your compiled applies to your source texts, literal strings included. A compiler, if I'm not wrong, normalizes each translation unit (source code file) to an encoding of its choice to handle the file.

I don't really know what happens under the hood, but perhaps you have read something somewhere about source file/internal encoding, and 16 bits/32bits encodings and all the mess is blended on your head. I'm still confused either though.

Comment: Unicode is absolutely a character set; it defines a set of characters, assigning each one an abstract code point. UTF-8 is an *encoding* of the Unicode character set, which maps each code point to a concrete sequence of bytes (possible of length 1). UTF-16 is a different encoding of the Unicode character set. CP-1252 is a one-byte encoding of a set of characters; the exact set of characters has no name, so it is sometimes confusingly also called CP-1252. (CP stands for "code page" so it clearly refers to the mapping.)

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 *byte* by definition, where a "byte" is 8 or more bits. (The C standard has its own definition of "byte". It's not necessarily the same as an octet, which is exactly 8 bits.)  A C++ implementation *can* have 16-bit or 32-bit bytes, but encodings like UTF-8 make it possible to represent Unicode with just 8-bit bytes.

Comment: Are you sure the C++ standard says `sizeof(char)` must be at least 8 bits long?